# Should I always call .ToArray on LINQ query results returned in a function?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, return, return-value

I've run into quite a few cases of `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute` errors when returning the results of a LINQ query in a function, like this... (I should add the function acts as an implementation of an interface and the results leave this module to be used in another.)

```
Public Function GetTheFuzzyFuzzbuzzes() As IEnumerable(of FuzzBuzz) _
    Implements IFoo.GetTheFuzzyFuzzBuzzes

    Return mySecretDataSource.Where(Function(x) x.IsFuzzy)
End Function
```

Should I, as a rule, always call `.ToArray` when returning the result of LINQ query in a function or property getter if the underlying data has potential to be changed? I know there's a bit of an efficiency hit in doing this, but I have a feeling it's the *safe* thing to do, and thus should always be done to avoid temporal coupling issues.

**Edit:**

Let me do a better job explaining the problem domain.

We have a graph based implementation of our main area of concern, which is an optimization problem. Entities are represented as graph nodes. Edges weighted with various costs and other parameters express relationships between the nodes . As the user manipulates the data, we create different edges and evaluate the various options they can take against the current state to give them feedback on each option's results. Changes made to the data on the server by other users and programs are propagated immediately to the client via push technology. We use a lot of threading ...

... all this means that we have a lot of stuff happening in a very asynchronous manner.

Our program is split into modules (based on the single responsibility principle) with a contract project and a resolved-at-run-time implementation project, which means we rely heavily on interfaces. We typically pass data between the modules using IEnumerable (since they are *kind-of-sort-of* immutable).

Comment: could you post a small, compile-able version of a program that reproduces this?

Comment: Unfortunately our code-base is like 50000+ LOC with 68 projects so producing a good example will be kind of tough. See the expanded detail in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, I would not make a rule of this.

I understand your concern. The calling side might not be aware that it's actions affect results of the query.

There are a few cases where you really can't do this:

- There are examples where doing so would cause an out of memory, such as with infinite enumerables, or in enumerator that produces a newly computed image each iteration. (I have both).
- If you use `Any()` or `First()` on your queries. Both require only reading the first element. All other work is done in vain.
- If you expect Enumerables to be chained with pipes/filters. Materializing the intermediate results is only extra cost.

On the other hand, in many cases it is safer to materialize the query into an array when it is conceivable that the use of the array will have side effects that will affect the query.

When writing software it sounds appealing to have rules that say "When you need to choose between X and Y, always do X". I don't believe there are any such rules. Maybe in 15% you really should do X, in 5% you definetly need to do Y, and for the rest of the cases, it just does not matter.

For those remaining 80%, doing nothing might be the appropriate thing. If you insert `ToArray()` everywhere, the code wrongfully suggests that there was a reason why this is done.

Comment: +1 for "the code wrongfully suggests that there was a reason why this is done". When a line of code is written, no one will never fell safe to remove it. It often result in spaghetti code as time goes by.

Answer (score 5):

In general you shouldn't **always** call `.ToArray` or `.ToList` when returning the result of LINQ query.

Both `.ToArray` and `.ToList` are "greedy" (opposite to lazy) operations that actually perform query to source of your data. And suitable place and time to call them are architecture decision. For example you could establish a rule in your project to materialize all linq queries inside Data Access Layer, and thus handle all data layer exception there. Or to have them not executed as long as it's possible and only get required data at very end. And there are many other details related to this topic.

But to call, or not to call `.ToArray` when returning result from your function — this is not an question and it has no answer until you present more detailed sample.

Comment: I've added more detail to the question (although not a detailed code sample), if you would like to update your answer...

Comment: Key point is _our program is split into modules (based on the **single responsibility principle**)_ — would you like not to mix and how are you going to split _data access_ and _graph based implementation of our main area of concern_? And this answer is individual for every project

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to return an IEnumerable (or IQueryable, or anything like those that isn't self-contained), the restrictions on when it can be called, what can be done with it or how long it can be held onto need to be clearly spelled out.

For those reasons, I'd recommend returning `FuzzBuzz[]` instead of `IEnumerable<FuzzBuzz>` if this is an API of some kind (ie. between layers).  If this is part of the internal implementation of a class/module, it's easier to justify a delay-evaluated `IEnumerable<FuzzBuzz>`, but still reasonable to use the array.

Unless the number of results is large, or this is called frequently, it's unlikely to be a performance concern (in many scenarios, CPU time is cheap, and the memory allocated to the array won't be kept around very long).

Comment: Should be mentioned that in some situations(like NHibernate's Linq implementation), implicitly casting IQueryable<T> to IEnumerable<T> will cause the the query to be ran.

Comment: I like the mention that the return type should be an API decision. I think there are too many of us who fail to think about the API we're inflicting on our fellows.

Answer (score 2):

"As a rule", No, you shouldn't always call ToList/ToArray. Otherwise, queries such as `myData.GetSomeSubset().WhereOtherCondition().Join(otherdata)` spends a bunch of time allocating temporary buffers for each chained call. But LINQ works best with immutable collections. You might want to be more careful at the point where you modify `mySecretDataSource`.

Specifically, if your code is always structured around frequent modification of your datasource, that sounds like a good reason to eagerly return an array instead of an IEnumerable